# Search&replace notepad regex to be used one

Tags: regex, notepad

I have strings like is below,

`nn"h11p3ppppvxq3b288N1 m 227"]`
`{vanxtageendganmesbhorgtgt(1702)}'` d3zd6xf8dz8xd6dz8f6zd8`

`[nn"5rvh11p3ppppvxq3b288N1 n 227"]`
`{vanxtageendganmesbhorgtgt(1802)}`
`d3zd6xf8dz8xd6dz8f6zd8`

I start my 1st capturing group from m 227 till end of  third line,
And my 2nd group from n 227 till end of third line .....
Now I want to add some digits to end of  first captured group , say it -22
And some digits to end of second captured group, say it -11
My first regex can match and works separately so 2nd as well .... but to make them combine with `|` it doesn't .....

Search: `(m\s.*\n.*\n.*)`
Replace: `$1 -22`

My combined regex is as below

`(m\s.*\n.*\n.*|n\s.*\n.*\n.*)`

Replace: `$1-22 $2-11`

But this will add (-22 -11) to both intendeds ...

I want the output to be as below

`nn"h11p3ppppvxq3b288N1 m 227"]`
`{vanxtageendganmesbhorgtgt(1702)}`
`d3zd6xf8dz8xd6dz8f6zd8 -22`

`[nn"5rvh11p3ppppvxq3b288N1 n 227"]`
`{vanxtageendganmesbhorgtgt(1802)}`
`d3zd6xf8dz8xd6dz8f6zd8 -11`

I have used `|` or for to combine both regexes to works as one for the purpose of time Savage ....

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**Find What**: `([mn])\s.*\R.*\R.*`
**Replace With**: `$& -$1`

*Details*:

- `([mn])` - Group 1 (`$1`): `m` ior `n`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `.*\R.*\R.*` - a line, a line break, then again a line and a line break and then a line.

The `$&` in the replacement is the backreference to the whole match.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor, ,  as I'm new user,  please teach me how to give thanks or a badge?

Comment: What if I wanted to add 22 to m and 11 to n ? What will be the backreferance and regex?  Thanks once again

Comment: @حاجيرحمتالله Find `(?:(m)|n)\s.*\R.*\R.*` and replace with `$& -(?{1}22:11)`, if I understood you well.

Comment: Sorry didn't work as was desired it just added  -(?{1}22:11), ,,, I'm using a mobile notepad version  called notepadmm

Comment: @حاجيرحمتالله Use the Notepad++ full version if you need a conditional replacement. Else, it is not possible.

Comment: At first I considered your answer helpful,  but it was charming,  I still need an answer as intended, I'm sorry for my English, I started my captured group one from M till two last lines, so I want to add at the third line which is end of my first captured group a desired digits,,,, and so a different desired digits to second's captured group as well....but your answer was charming looking as I gave the example,  but not as I wanted....